CSS Nesting Help! I need the elements to react only to parent class, basically unset at each class level


<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container mt-3">
    <h2>Nesting Div Class Example</h2>
      
        <div class="bg-dark">
            <h1>Outer</h1>
            <p>outer text</p>
            <div class="bg-light">                 
                <h1>Inner</h1>
                <p>Inner text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<style>
    .bg-light,.bg-light h1{    
        color:black;
    }
     .bg-dark,.bg-dark h1{
        color:white;
    }     
</style>

** I need bg-light class to not react to the bg-dark class, so that no matter which class is the parent that it doesn't adopt the parents styling
I have attempted to use !important tags, unset, initial, and :where() to adjust the specificity but  I need the lowest level or layer class only to dictate the styling. I am trying to set up a end product that has 10 background options with predefined text, link, title, colors where no matter how they are nested there is clear contrast. I am wanting a reusable code that for each site I can adjust the background color and overlay text, link, title colors per class. Is this even possible!? I have been stuck on this issue for awhile any help is appreciated. Also I am only looking to modify css to fix this issue. My work around has been that I account for every combination ".bg-light .bg-dark{color:here}" and then ".bg-dark .bg-light {color:here}" but I am hoping there is a better way

.bg-light {color:black;}.bg-dark {color:white;} ?

sorry I am trying to account for text inside of the div as well, really any element inside of the div

try the code ....

Please improve the clarity of your post. Edit it to include a screenshot or two. It’s not clear to me what the problem is.

You have not included any screenshots in your post, so it’s difficult to guess exactly what the problem is that you’re trying to solve.
The basic technique in CSS is that any styles which are directly applied to an element override any styles which they inherit from their ancestors. You do not need to “unset” the styles inherited from your ancestors, you need to override them.
In the snippet below, the class .bg-light specifies a white background and black text. The element with this class is rendered with a white background and black text because these styles override the black background and white text styles it inherits from its .bg-dark ancestor.


.bg-dark {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}     

.bg-light {    
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
<div class="container mt-3">
    <h2>Contextual Backgrounds</h2>
        <p>Use the contextual background classes to provide "meaning through colors".</p>
        <div class="bg-dark">
            <h1>Outer</h1>
            <p>outer text</p>
            <div class="bg-light">                 
                <h1>Inner</h1>
                <p>Inner text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>



